# QGIS Time Manager Data entry

Tags: qgis, animation

I have downloaded the Time Manager plugin for QGIS.  I have created a simple test file with only 4 points, with a date attribute showing YYYY-MM-DD, each point moving forward one day.  Yet it tells me that the attribute selected for use as start time contains invalid data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the files?

Answer (score 2):

How have you created the test file? Open your attribute table and have a look at how the data actually appears. If you used, for example, OpenOffice or Excel to edit a CSV file and make a date column, it may store the date in a different numeric format, even though it displays YYYY-MM-DD in the spreadsheet.

Works for me (QGIS 1.7.4, OSX 10.7) using data in a 'date' column like the one following (I entered the data manually within QGIS, as a text field):

```
date
2012-05-19
2012-05-20
```

Check whether you have extra spaces before or after your date entry, too.

Comment: I entered the dates originally using the Calendar edit widget.  Having gone back and put them in manually, it now works. Thanks for your help.